# Father & Mother Issue.!

Tags: halal-haram, sin, parents, muslim-practices, children

Assalam o Allaikum everyone. A couple of days ago my friend asked me a question to which I am still kinda confused.

He said,

> "My dad and mom usually quarrel a lot and both of them hate other's
> family. So, when I or my brother visit any relative from my mom's side
> of the family my father isn't happy with us and vice-versa. Also, my
> mom tells me something to do and dad says not to do it. I literally do
> no understand what to do and it becomes so frustrating that sometimes
> I just leave the house for a couple of hours. I don't know what to do
> and want to know the proper Islamic point of view on this situation
> and whether I become a sinner for not listening to any one of them.?"

I didn't know what to say hence I think posting this here could help me out get some answers. Thank you.

Comment: Relevant: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55725/

Comment: Is there any specific reason on why the parents don't like the kids visiting the other sides relatives? Or is it only because the parents have "personal" issues with one another while the relatives have nothing to do with?

Comment: Only once he asked to which he got the reply, " I don't like them". He never asked again.

Comment: @UmH Thanks mate.